# How to keep a 2 person team together while my colleague doesn't work by my side?

Tags: teamwork

I have been in a deep friendship with one of my classmates since 3 years ago. we've been studying, working and having fun together with high efficiency but it didn't last. It's been 4 months since he started to care less about our work and project & he says he has some personal issues. But I keep hearing from the others and himself that he goes to several parties and wedding ceremonies, singing class and stuff while he keeps saying that he has money issues. 
What should I do? shall I break up with him?

Comment: Going to parties or wedding ceremonies doesn't mean anything, it doesn't have to cost a dime. I'd encourage someone to have a good time, especially when they are feeling sad or having issues. You have to make a decision whether you want to stay friends or make him understand that you only want a professional relationship. It's very understandable for him to express his problems to you if you're friends.

Comment: To clarify--are you both employees at the same job, or are you working together on independent projects, or what? If you're co-employees, you might not be able to "break up with him."

Comment: @JoeStrazzere You mean as friends or as colleges or both?

Comment: I find this whole text very confusing. You guys are buddies, and hanged out a lot, as well as work together, but now he seems to be excluding you from his life, and not performing as well at work, and you're asking _us_ whether you should maintain a social relationship with the guy? How the heck would we know? If you feel hurt because you're not a part of this person's social life anymore, I suggest you start making more friends. If you are concerned about a lack of performance at work, tell him as much. Unless you're his boss, however, it's not your job to discipline him.

Answer (score 2):

The situation should be handled just as if he were a regular employee. However, you are friends, so you must be able to exclude the two roles into two separate categories. What he tells you as a friend should not be used against him in his professional role, instead you should use the knowledge to help if possible. If it's not possible in your opinion, focus on the professional path.

As friends its only natural for him to express his feelings to you in a wider range than he'd do to a casual co-worker or employer, that includes his problems. Friends are not all about sharing happiness, it's about the hard things in life, too.

If he's really slacking at work then his boss, whether that's you or someone else, needs to have a talk about it and make professional decisions. I would be really careful about linking what he does in his personal time to how he's performing at work, however. Just because he tries to have fun doesn't mean it's the source of his problems, it doesn't even have to cost him a dime and even if it did it shouldn't matter, what he does outside of work should not concern his employer (in general). I'd encourage someone in his position to try to have a good time.

It's important to find out what's really causing his slack, by asking him but not making assumptions, and if his personal life is the real problem then it's up to the person in charge to decide how the company is going to proceed, whether it's to lay him off or to do what's possible to help him in that situation.

If its important to lay him off then you can always try to remain friends, that's up to you guys, but I don't think asking whether you should stop being friends due to him not being able to remain purely professional is the right question.

tl;dr: remain professional, even if it means laying him off, but don't make assumptions based on his private life. Asking whether you should be friends or not is not something we can tell you, but the friendship can carry on even if the business relationship disappears.